# Access hiddenfield using Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, hiddenfield

I have a page that's derived from a master page. On this page, I have a hiddenfield ("hfUser"). How can I access this "hfUser" control and get/set its value using JQuery?
I've tried variants of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = $("#hfUser").val();
    alert(test);

});
```

but test = undefined. I'm guessing I've got the selector wrong, but I don't know how to get an asp hiddenfield. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure `hfUser` is the `id` and not the `name`? if its the name then `$('input[name=hfUser]');` should gt your the field.

Comment: Hi, it was the ID and not the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Asp.net controls, the server will mangle the control ids. It adds a bunch of extraneous control tree hierarchy information into the id.  You need to reference what that acutal id is that's getting rendered, which is availble with the ClientID property on the control (hfUser.ClientID) or access your control in a different, more roundabout way, like find the controls parent, then search through its children to find your control.

If you don't have to use the asp.net HiddenField control, try just using a regular old html input.

Answer (score 3):

ASP does like to mangle ID's.  The further down the rabbit hole (or nesting controls) you go, the more ASP adds to your control ID.  Throw in Master Pages, and it's yet another level or two.

Another way to access server-side controls (with the runat property set), is to use the square brackets in your jQuery selector.

Like this:

```
$("[id$='hidImgSource']").val()
```

That selects any elements whose ID has 'hidImgSource' as ending part of the name.  So it will find mangled ID's.

Here is a link to the [jQuery Selectors page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that explains some more options.

Answer (score 2):

If the hidden field is an ASP.NET control, check out this blog post to help you with jQuery selectors for ASP.NET controls

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/extending-jquery-to-select-asp-controls/

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var test = $("**#<%= hfUser.ClientID %>**").val();
    alert(test);
});
```